# Referential Integrity (Inserting Data to two or more tables)

Tags: sql, vb.net, database-design

I want to ask if is it possible to insert a row of data to two or more tables:

sample query:

insert into tblsample, tblsample2 ('tblsample.id','tblsample2.id'') values ('1','1')

well i believe the syntax is wrong but what i want to show is the process that could have been done.

I am thinking of doing this into a transaction query like if this idea doesn't work.

Comment: i put referential integrity there because i was thinking that when you add a certain data to a table you must put a data to the other table with referential integrity from the first table. That is also my concern if i'll add to the first table would that be a problem if i don't do something to the other table.

Comment: Do you have a specific database you are working with? MS SQL, Oracle, MS Access, Etc..

Comment: MS Access as a requirement from a teacher. In my own preference I am comfortable at using Mysql server but as what she needs. I am using MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle seems to support multi table insert like this:

```
insert all
into sample_table (id, name) values (1, 'foo')
into sample_table2 (id, name) values (2, 'bar')
select * from dual;
```

But I think there is no vendor independent way.

Comment: I would like to try Oracle. Thank Btw.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible in Standard SQL. Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server and probably other DBMSs allow multi-table inserts with certain limitations.

The restriction that only one table can be modified at once is a fundamental limitation of SQL. It makes it practically impossible to enforce some multi-table integrity constraints. That is probably why SQL DBMSs usually only support a very limited set of constraints (FOREIGN KEYs and some CHECK constraints).

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL and Oracle can support multiple inserts, but you should wrap in a transaction because if half way through an error occurs, it will not roll back the whole SQL Statement. To do this, add a ";" between your inserts:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (1,2,3,'Test');INSERT INTO table1 (3,4,5,'Test');INSERT INTO table1 (6,7,8,'Test')
```

But, a little trick you can do with MS Access is create a table of data to insert by UNIONing some data together:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (SELECT 1,2,3,'TEST' UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,3,'TEST' UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,3,'TEST')
```

*I may have the MS Access syntax wrong, its been a while since I did this with access*

This also works with many other databases but thier syntax might be different. Nice thing about this approach is it is already transactional so you dont have to wrap it in a transaction.